# Problem with PCA

Tags: r, clustering, pca, correspondence-analysis

I am trying to do some PC analysis on my data coming from lipids measurements in different samples. I only have one factor: if samples are diabetic or non-dibetic. Here is the PCA graph I get:

[image]

As you can see, data are not clustered at all! What should I do for that? Is there any other clustration analysis I can use instead of PCA?

Comment: It would really help if you could post a reproducible example.  As currently stated, your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, and

1. you have two different classes as diabetic/non-diabetic,
2. you want to preserve class-discriminatory information while reducing dimension, you should use Linear Discriminant Analysis and not PCA. Below is a copy/paste from Wikipedia:

LDA is closely related to principal component analysis (PCA) and factor analysis in that they both look for linear combinations of variables which best explain the data.[4] LDA explicitly attempts to model the difference between the classes of data. PCA on the other hand does not take into account any difference in class, and factor analysis builds the feature combinations based on differences rather than similarities. Discriminant analysis is also different from factor analysis in that it is not an interdependence technique: a distinction between independent variables and dependent variables (also called criterion variables) must be made.

LDA works when the measurements made on independent variables for each observation are continuous quantities. When dealing with categorical independent variables, the equivalent technique is discriminant correspondence analysis. [5][6]

Answer (score 1):

### PCA is sensitive to outliers.

Try removing the outlier, and running PCA again, or try a **robust PCA** approach.

From the Wikipedia article on PCA, section "Robustness – weighted PCA":

> Kriegel, H. P.; Kröger, P.; Schubert, E.; Zimek, A. (2008).
>  **A General Framework for Increasing the Robustness of PCA-Based Correlation Clustering Algorithms**.
>  Scientific and Statistical Database Management. Lecture Notes in Computer Science 5069: 418. doi:10.1007/978-3-540-69497-7_27. ISBN 978-3-540-69476-2.

(which is specific literature for clustering! Roughly the idea is that you try to give less weight to the outliers, such that PCA is less influenced by it.)

Also check the various literature given in the [Robust principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_principal_component_analysis) article; too much to copy here.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused with the description of your data: you said that you only have one factor? PCA is usually used when one has many variables and wants to reduce the data down to just a few (principal) components.

You may want to consider looking at different perspectives of this plot. Notice you have PC1 plotted against PC2. Maybe if you looked at PC2 plotted against PC3 you might see some clustering.

That said, there are [lots](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) of clustering techniques available in R, maybe you should consider those?